# Limite de banda no IIS 8.5 não funciona?

Tags: iis

Estou tentando limitar a banda em um website no `IIS 8.5` rodando no `Windows 2012 R2` mas não está surtindo efeito e tentei de tudo verifiquei todas as configurações e não consigo encontrar o problema

Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Comment: Relacionado: https://iisbrasil.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/configurando-limites-de-web-site/ se viu esse link?

Comment: Sim já vi, como disse não funciona a configuração, inclusive uma pessoa nos comentários disse que com ela não estava funcionando também, só que não voltou para dizer se conseguiu resolver o problema...

Comment: Sinceramente é por ai mesmo que é a configuração se está testando como?

Comment: O website eu configurei para usar apenas 5mb e o servidor da pico de 60mb de banda, se eu dou stop no pool do website limitado o uso de rede do servidor despenca pela metade, se eu volto o pool o uso de rede vai lá e cima, como e um subdominio para as imagens eu queria limitar o uso da banda...

Comment: Tentei também configurar o Bit Rate Throttling um modulo do Web Plataform também não funcionou...

Comment: Estou achando que existe alguma dependência, algum serviço do windows precisa ser ativado ou pode ser alguma configuração do website interferindo, como a falta de algum Handler ou Modulo